# Java ResultSet.getString() for Date field skips millisecond

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset, ojdbc

I am using ojdbc8 version 21.3.0.0 and am retrieving the Date column in Oracle as a string.
I was expecting the string to be printed as 2021-01-21 00:00:00.0 but it prints as 2021-01-21 00:00:00 , so millisecond is skipped.
Wondering why this change?
Is there a way that getString() of ResultSet still return with millisecond, that's 2021-01-21 00:00:00.0 ?

ojdbc8 12.2 returned in this format 2021-01-21 00:00:00.0. With version upgrade this change is observed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type stored as 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and seconds. The values are all integers so there will **NEVER** be any fractional seconds.

If you want fractional seconds then you need to use a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

If you want to display the time with fractional seconds then you will need to format the date and explicitly print the zero fractional seconds (which you could do by concatenating `".0"` onto your string).

Comment: With ojdbc8 12.2 ResultSet getString() returned 2021-01-21 00:00:00.0. With version upgrade I see this change.

Comment: @user2359634 That sounds like something has changed in how the driver implicitly formats dates as strings. You can either continue to rely on the implicit date format and adjust your code whenever the driver changes (in this case, append `".0"` to the result; but if the driver's behaviour changes again you'll need to fix it again) or you can swap to explicitly formatting the date and that way you will always know what the format will be.

Answer (score 0):

The latest drivers have the correct behavior. A DATE type doesn't include milliseconds in Oracle. Please refer to the document [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B).